# Groovy: What happens when a closure's "owner" is another closure

Tags: groovy

I came across the concept of the `owner` of a closure in Groovy and it confused me, so I wrote a tiny program to figure out how `owner` works:

```
def examineClosure(closure) {
  closure()
}
examineClosure() {
    println "$owner"
    examineClosure() {
        println "$owner"
    }
}
```

When I ran this code, though, I got a `java.lang.StackOverflowError`, which I assume is because when `$owner` is evaluated in the inner closure, Groovy is actually executing `.call()` implicitly on the outer closure. Is this expected behavior? Why would the result not be identical to

```
examineClosure() {
    println "$owner"
    examineClosure() {
        println "" + owner
    }
}
```

It was my understanding that `"some var: $var"` was simply Groovy shorthand for `"some var: " + var`

Answer (score 0):

The syntax "$owner" using Groovy means the following: Insert the 'owner' variable value as a string into the " " section.

That cause due to the [GString definition in Groovy](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/index.html#_string_interpolation).

An example for using GString can be as followed:

```
String $outerValue = "groovy GString syntax"

"This is a String using $outerValue. it makes the String clear and more readable"."
```

Hence I am not sure the error you have related to the closure section.

unfortunately, your assumption:

> It was my understanding that "some var: $var" was simply Groovy
>   shorthand for "some var: " + var

is wrong.

In the following code:

```
examineClosure() {
    println "$owner"
    examineClosure() {
        println "" + owner
    }
}
```

The variable **owner** is not defined at all.

And that is why you get the java.lang.StackOverflowError.

Comment: the variables `this`, `owner`, and `delegate` are defined implicitly within the scope of any closure in Groovy: http://groovy-lang.org/closures.html#closure-owner

Comment: But the line: println "" + owner means that the owner is a String or implements toString() method so it can be printed into the screen. and I don't see any implementation for that in your code. when you have one than it can be printed.